# Sticky Navigation - Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble creating a sticky navigation, i have researched many tutorials and have looked through stack overflow, but i find it all quite complicated or it just doesn't work in the end, I am a beginner programmer and I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on my situation.
**The bold is what i have written for the sticky navigation
** I am very sorry if the way I formatted this question incorrectly
and would it alright if you post a paste bin of my css file but change it so that it works, and then comment the link, because it would prove to be very easy for me because i don't always understand the comments that i'm given

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// define variables
var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

// add utility wrapper elements for positioning
jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
jQuery("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
jQuery(".nav-inner").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"></div>');

// function to run on page load and window resize
function stickyUtility() {

    // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
    if (!jQuery("nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
        navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
    }

    // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
    jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

} // end stickyUtility function

// run on page load
stickyUtility();

// run on window resize
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    stickyUtility();
});

// run on scroll event
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
        jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }

});
```

});

---

Html:
http://pastebin.com/MSfbQxdv
CSS:
http://pastebin.com/v0VrGf3T

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to make your header "sticky" then you can simply use that CSS instead of JavaScript:

```
#navMenu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 200px;        // 200px is just an example
}

#main {
        margin-top: 200px;   // Same as #navMenu height, so the top portion of the content stays below #navMenu 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me out, i tried out what you said, but for some reason it wont work, is it alright if you post a paste bin  of my css file but change it so that it works, and then comment the link,

Comment: Make sure to either: drop that bit of CSS at the very end of your file so the previous rules don't overwrite it, or to modify the properties in the selectors you already have.

Comment: I have and still hasnt worked, is it alright if you can try what i commented earlier, this is starting to become a issue for me

Comment: Read up about the CSS `position` property if you want to understand this better.